# Exporting a 10.0 Crystal report to PDF results in a blank PDF document(works on development machine does not work on other machines)

Tags: crystal-reports, report

I have a small program developed using C#(dotnet 2.0 framework)  and MySql 5.0 that reads data from a MySql database opens a report then exports the data to a PDF document . The program is working fine on my development machine .

I created a ClickOnce installation using VIsual Studio 2005 .Using that setup I installed the program on another computer on which crystal reports 10.0 and dot net framework 2.0  was not installed.

I installed dot net framework 2.0 and crystal redistributable for visual studio 2005 on the other machine.

On the other machine the program runs without any error . **But the generated PDF file does not contain any data**.

I exported the contents of the dataset(I am using the Push Model ) to an XML file to ensure that data is being retrieved .

Data is being retrieved as expected . But the generated PDF document is blank

Please note that I am using the 'MySQl Connector' to connect to MySql. Also the development machine is a Windows XP machine 
The other computer is a Windows 2003 Server.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem too. Sometimes

1. I delete the temporary folder
2. Use CCleaner to clean
3. Set Security Policy to clean Virtual memory on shut down
4. Shut down + Switch on the system
5. Clearing history and cache
6. Combo of above 5

But now nothing is working for me. The crystal report shows data and design. Using crystal report's export to pdf option, the pdf works fine. But when exporting directly, the pdf has many pages which are blank. Not even design is showing.